# Text message is not displaying properly

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper-reports 4.5.0 to generate the reports. I am generating the reports in pdf,csv,html formats. If there are no matching records in the database then I am displaying the message as `There Are No Matching Records`.

The problem is it is not displaying the message properly. It is displaying the message as `There Are No Matchino Records To Displav`, The `y` is displaying as `v` and `g` is displaying as `o`. The alignment to this text is center.

The same problem is happening for the footer message also. The problem is only happening on the html report, the pdf looks correct.

**Why it is displaying the message like this and how do I fix it?**

```
<noData>
        <band height="45">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="466" height="45" forecolor="#FF0000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[There Are No Matching Records To Display]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </noData>
```

The pbm is in only html format.

Comment: Are you talking about *staticText* (or *textField*) element?

Comment: statc text only if it is y then it is cutting the below line and showing as v.Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot? Your question and your comment are unclear

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the box the static text is in is not tall enough to fit the text with what ever font you have set for it. The reason it does not happen for pdf, (from my understanding) use a different set of fonts. Essentially you got lucky and the font it used fit in the height you gave the field.

The solution is to make the static text box height taller. The same should work with the footer also. I would try increasing the size by increments of 10 until it fits. You can then back down by 1 or 2 to get it as small as possible while still allowing it all to fit.

Comment: Hi jschoen.Thanks for giving the reply.If i increase the size of the static text box then also i am getting the same problem.

Comment: You need to update your question with the JRXML then, with out being able to see it there is not much anyone can do to help.